# pandas dataframe slicing - pythonic idiom for order of row v column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, slice

I am in the middle of the DataCamp "Pandas Foundations" course. This is the section on partial string indexing in [time series with pandas](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/pandas-foundations/time-series-in-pandas).

Given a DataFrame of this format

```
                     Temperature  DewPoint  Pressure
Date                                                
2010-01-01 00:00:00         46.2      37.5       1.0
2010-01-01 01:00:00         44.6      37.1       1.0
2010-01-01 02:00:00         44.1      36.9       1.0
2010-01-01 03:00:00         43.8      36.9       1.0
2010-01-01 04:00:00         43.5      36.8       1.0
2010-01-01 05:00:00         43.3      37.3       1.0
...
2010-01-01 21:00:00         48.1      38.5       1.0
2010-01-01 22:00:00         47.2      38.5       1.0
2010-01-01 23:00:00         46.4      38.4       1.0
2010-01-02 00:00:00         46.5      38.2       1.0
2010-01-02 01:00:00         44.9      37.8       1.0
...                          ...       ...       ...
2010-12-31 22:00:00         46.9      37.9       1.0
2010-12-31 23:00:00         46.2      37.7       1.0
```

In previous exercises, they used the following formula to extract only some rows, using partial string indexing:

```
df1 = df.loc['2010-Aug-01':'2010-Aug-15', 'Temperature']
```

However, in the current exercise, they are using another formula **which works**:

```
df2 = df['Temperature']['2010-Aug-01':'2010-Aug-15']
```

I liked this because of its simplicity. However, the placement of the labels seemed counter-intuitive, so for experimentation purposes, I tried:

```
df3 = df['2010-Aug-01':'2010-Aug-15']['Temperature']
```

which appears to be equivalent (it gave the same results).

I assume pandas is "smart enough" to do the right thing, but I was surprised. I was thinking dictionary format and would have assumed the index (key) should come first with the value (column) choice second.

Is there a recommended order?

```
[column][index]
```

vs

```
[index][column]
```

for writing the code or does it not matter how I write it because pandas understands and so would anyone reading the code?

**Note**: The question here is not "how do I extract rows with partial string indexing in pandas?". Please do not tell me that `.loc` is your personal favorite or the only way you've ever used, or the only way you think "works". If all you know about is `.loc`, this is not a question you will be able to answer unless you stretch your mind to include other possibilities. I know about `.loc` and `.loc` is **not** the answer to this question. (I wish I didn't have to say this.)

Answer (score 2):

You should using `.loc`

```
d1 = df.loc['2010-08-01':'2010-08-15','Temperature']
```

Comment: Yes, and I have (also) done that. That's not the question here.

Comment: Neither way you've suggested are recommended.  @WeNYoBen has offered you the way that they **can** recommend.

Comment: @VickiB I recommend using .loc , since you pass those slicing to pandas , then why not using pandas' function like loc iloc ?

Comment: Once more, his question is not asking for a recommendation beyond what you see here. SInce that seems to be something no one can understand, I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @VickiB I will only say using .loc rather than chain the [], since that will cause some unsung error